# How to extend datetime.timedelta?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to extend the Python `datetime.timedelta` for use with cross country race results. I want to construct an object from a string in format `u"mm:ss.s"`. I am able to accomplish this using the factory design pattern and `@classmethod` annotation. How would I accomplish the same by overriding `__init__` and/or `__new__`?

With the code below, constructing an object raises a TypeError. Note that `__init__` is not called, because `'in my __init__'` is not printed.

```
import datetime
import re

class RaceTimedelta(datetime.timedelta):
    def __init__(self, timestr = ''):
        print 'in my __init__'
        m = re.match(r'(\d+):(\d+\.\d+)', timestr)
        if m:
            mins = int(m.group(1))
            secs = float(m.group(2))
            super(RaceTimedelta, self).__init__(minutes = mins, seconds = secs)
        else:
            raise ValueError('timestr not in format u"mm:ss.d"')
```

Here is the error:

```
>>> from mytimedelta import RaceTimedelta
>>> RaceTimedelta(u'24:45.7')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: unicode
>>>
```

If I move my code from `__init__` to `__new__`, I get the following. Note that this time, the output shows that my `__new__` function is called.

```
>>> RaceTimedelta(u'24:45.7')
in my __new__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mytimedelta.py", line 16, in __new__
    super(RaceTimedelta, self).__new__(minutes = mins, seconds = secs)
TypeError: datetime.timedelta.__new__(): not enough arguments
>>>
```

Comment: `datetime` is implemented in C. If you only want to replace the constructor, just having a convenience function to parse the string would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The end goal is to display the times in a table of race results. For that reason, I also want to override `__str__` to make it easier to work with a pretty printer module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently `timedelta` objects are immutable, which means their value is actually set in the class' `__new__()` method—so you'll need to override that method instead of its `__init__()`:

```
import datetime
import re

class RaceTimedelta(datetime.timedelta):
    def __new__(cls, timestr=''):
        m = re.match(r'(\d+):(\d+\.\d+)', timestr)
        if m:
            mins, secs = int(m.group(1)), float(m.group(2))
            return super(RaceTimedelta, cls).__new__(cls, minutes=mins, seconds=secs)
        else:
            raise ValueError('timestr argument not in format "mm:ss.d"')

print RaceTimedelta(u'24:45.7')
```

Output:

```
0:24:45.700000
```

BTW, I find it odd that you're providing a default value for the`timestr`keyword argument that will be considered illegal and raise a`ValueError`.

Comment: The thought with the invalid default value was to provide a friendlier error message in the case of `RaceTimedelta()`.

Comment: I see. Perhaps changing it to `def __new__(cls, timestr='no default'):` or adding a comment would make things more clear (to others reading the code).