# TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm stumped by this inheritance behavior in Python. As far as I can tell the super class constructor is being called correctly although the syntax differs from 2.7 to 3.5.

```
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> 
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> class MyTimestamp(pd.Timestamp):
...     def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
...         super(MyTimestamp, self).__init__(arg, **kwargs)
... 
>>> a=MyTimestamp(1312342152423, unit='us')
>>> a
Timestamp('1970-01-16 04:32:22.152423')
```

Using a Python 3.5.1 interpreter I get the following result, both have the same version of Pandas installed (0.18.0) but I believe it is more a Python inheritance thing.

```
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> class MyTimestamp(pd.Timestamp):
...     def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
...         super().__init__(arg, **kwargs)
... 
>>> a=MyTimestamp(1312342152423, unit='us')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__

TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

The `mro` for `MyTimestamp` specifies:

```
(<class '__main__.MyTimestamp'>, 
 <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>, 
 <class 'pandas.tslib._Timestamp'>, 
 <class 'datetime.datetime'>, 
 <class 'datetime.date'>, 
 <class 'object'>)
```

so `object` is not the next class in the resolution order.   Where is this error coming from and perhaps more to the point what am I doing incorrectly that I can change to fix the issue?

Comment: Hmm ... Your supers don't look the same to me.  Shouldn't the python2.x version be `super(MyTimestamp, self).__init__(arg, **kwargs)`?  (i.e. you have an extra `self` in the python2.x version)

Comment: @mgilson: True (fixed that) but it still get the same results

Comment: Note that Python3 still supports the Python2 syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in this case, you should be overriding `__new__`. It seems panda's Timestamp is immutable (like datetime that it inherits from) so it's `__init__` method does nothing.

The way you wrote it works fine with python 3. Substitute `pd.Timestamp` with your own custom class and you will see super gets called normally.

Similar problem and solution: [Python: how to extend datetime.timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430269/python-how-to-extend-datetime-timedelta)

Comment: Yeah, it seems like `__new__` is the way to go: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tslib.pyx#L291

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this has anything to do with your use of super. If you test that same code with another class, it works fine. E.g.:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print ("Foo",arg)

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super().__init__(arg)

b=Bar(1) #Prints "Foo 1"
```

It seems like Pandas is doing something odd with that Timestamp class, and I can't exactly figure out what, but it's something to do with C extensions:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tslib.pyx#L222
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tslib.pyx#L881

Anyway, the following seems to work as intended:

```
import pandas

class MyTimestamp(pandas.Timestamp):
    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        pass

a=MyTimestamp(1312342152423, unit='us') #Timestamp('1970-01-16 04:32:22.152423')
```

Also, take a look at the variation in output between these two definitions:

```
import pandas

class MyTimestamp(pandas.Timestamp):
    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        print(super().__init__)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print ("Foo",arg)

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print(super().__init__)

a=MyTimestamp(1612342152423, unit='us')
b=Bar(1)
```

Which yields:

```
<method-wrapper '__init__' of MyTimestamp object at 0x04981AD0>
<bound method Foo.__init__ of <__main__.Bar object at 0x033C2070>>
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful

Comment: You are right: the same happens with `decimal.Decimal`, which is a C extension.